# Bot don't want to remove member's reaction

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have an authorization system on my server. When member reacts to message, he's getting access to stuff like chats etc. I want bot to remove reaction left by member, so number of reactions on the message will always=1

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message=payload.reaction.message

    if payload.channel_id==804320454152028170:
        if str(payload.emoji) == '✅':
            await message.remove_reaction("✅", payload.member)
        else:
            return
```

When I am leaving reaction under the message, I am getting this error:

```
message=payload.reaction.message
AttributeError: 'RawReactionActionEvent' object has no attribute 'reaction'
Ignoring exception in on_message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your error message! Looking at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) you can easily find out that `payload` simply does not have such attribute.
To get a message from `payload` you will need to do something like this

```
guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
channel = guild.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
```